# What is the meaning of the checksum meta tag?

Tags: html, meta-tags, checksum

I have a slight idea of what a [**Checksum**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) is, but little about why I would need such a tag on a site.  I see it a lot, implemented on news websites. For example on [this article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-05-07/hackers-target-who-by-posing-as-think-tank-broadcaster?srnd=code-wars) on Bloomberg, it has the following meta tag.

```html
<meta name="checksum" content="cfdf99753af393dc63329d195d692609">
```

What's its significance? Why does the site need it? Who creates/issues/validates the string in the `content`? What does the site loose if it's not included?

Comment: its purpose is to check the page integrity , but could be also used for caching purpose. As far as I know, it's not standardized, so probably is used inside the page for security/integrity reason (one example is to avoid that user changes  the web page content to make "fake image", and so when the content is edited, a script checks for the checksum, and if they are different, it reloads the page )

Comment: @Berto99, who uses it to check page integrity? The browser runtime, or third party vendors like social media sites(an example of those that give you tokens for apis). So this script checker, is it implemented by the site dev or browser inbuilt?

Comment: But who creates this checksum, and when is it updated if ever? Been trying to read about it but most of the write-ups I have found focus on what a checksum is, but not the meta tag.

Comment: I can’t tell, it’s not standardized, so you can’t have a unique interpretation of it, might be used by some news verification system, some internal service of the website, might be used on some scripts and so on